Nested Parameters in unix
export ABC=1
a="RESOLVED VALUE IS : ( \$ABC )"
echo $a

...emits as output:
RESOLVED VALUE IS : ( $ABC )

I would like to resolve the ABC parameter value when I do echo/eval or anything on param "a" and assign the final resolved value to a new parameter "b".
I tried using :
$ b=$(eval echo $a)
-bash: eval: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 1: `echo RESOLVED VALUE IS : ($ABC)'

I have also tried below two-way step and it worked, but looking for a one-liner solution without a temp file.
echo $a > temp.dat
b=$(envsubst < temp.dat)

echo $b

by contrast correctly had
RESOLVED VALUE IS : (1)


If you want to store code to run later, that's what functions are for. Things that act like variables but with deferred evaluation don't exist, and using them would be prone to security issues (similar to those eval has) if they did.

BTW, you're missing lots of quotes. Be sure to run your code through https://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds.

There are many reasons not to do this, but for the raw mechanics of using eval, you can do:
$ a="RESOLVED VALUE IS : ( \$ABC )"
$ ABC=foo
$ eval "b=\"$a\""
$ echo "$b"
RESOLVED VALUE IS : ( foo )
$ ABC=bar
$ eval "b=\"$a\""
$ echo "$b"
RESOLVED VALUE IS : ( bar )

eval just evaluates a string, and the string you want to evaluate is the (interpolated) assignment b="$a", so you just have to pass that string as an argument to eval.  In other words, the shell will interpolate $a and pass the desired string b="RESOLVED..." as the argument to eval, which then interpolates $ABC.
